# How to change laravel password directly in database?

Tags: laravel-5.3

Was building the change password feature but ended up locking myself out.
Have hashed the password before saving:

```
$user->password = Hash::make($request['password']);
$user->save();
```

I've also tried copying the hashed password in db from a known account to replace the password under my account, and I still couldn't log in with that account's password.

How do I change the password field in db directly?

Also,
How does laravel does it's password check? I've tried printing the output below and they change on every page refresh.

```
{{ bcrypt('mypassword') }}
{{ Hash::make('mypassword') }}
{{ password_hash('mypassword', PASSWORD_BCRYPT) }}
```

If it changes every time, how would it be able to check the stored password?

**Update**

So I used `tinker` and realised that I was looking at the wrong db! My bad. But I still don't understand why the password hash changes everytime. I still couldn't authenticate after saving a new password.

**Update 2**

After some reading hashing *will* always return a different value [[link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/hash-value-keep-changing)].
Also realise I saved the wrong input value causing the password saved to be wrong.

Comment: I was facing the same prb in laravel 5.4, and I want to replace my account password directly in database, I just clone 1 row and I change the user name and it works perfectly